# Simple computed field configuration in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, field

I have one field called field_domain

I have a computed field called field_graph

field_domain is filled in by the user.  For example it could be: drupal.org

I need computed field to inject the value of field_domain as a variable into field_graph, like so:

```
<a href='http://siteanalytics.compete.com/drupal.org/?metric=uv'><img src='http://grapher.compete.com/drupal.org_uv.png' /></a>
```

So field_domain is turned into a variable and put into the html

Example:

field_domain has a value of drupal.org.  This value gets turned into a variable of $domain

Computed field outputs:

```
<a href='http://siteanalytics.compete.com/$domain/?metric=uv'><img src='http://grapher.compete.com/$domain$under.png' /></a>
```

Putting the value of field_domain into wherever $domain is.

I have the code to do the conversion, put I don't know how to put it into computed field:

```
<?php
$domain = "drupal.org";
$under = "_uv";
echo "<a href='http://siteanalytics.compete.com/$domain/?metric=uv'><img src='http://grapher.compete.com/$domain$under.png' /></a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to a number of variables in the computed field. It tells you right there where you create it - see the help text below the text area where you type in your PHP? Also, where is $under coming from? If it's not hard coded, you'd have to change this code a little, but here's the gist:

```
$domain = $node->field_domain[0]['value'];
$node_field[0]['value'] = "<a href='http://siteanalytics.compete.com/$domain/?metric=uv'><img src='http://grapher.compete.com/{$domain}_uv.png' /></a>";
```

Comment: the original html is <a href='http://siteanalytics.compete.com/drupal.org/?metric=uv'><img src='http://grapher.compete.com/drupal.org_uv.png' /></a>.  In the image src, its, the domain followed by _uv.png.  But if I use $domain_uv.png instead of $domain$under.png, it wont render correctly. I have to use it as a variable.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I left the default Display Format as is, and used your code in the Computed Code, and it worked.  Thank you very much.

Comment: See my edit. You couldn't do $domain_uv because PHP parsed that as the variable name, which doesn't have a value. If put put $domain in curly braces, it's all good.

Comment: Ahhhh, simplified even more.  Thanks again.